# Close all web browser upon exit on Remote Desktop Session on Windows Server 2016

Tags: windows-server-2016

Is there any way or scripts need to do for this use case? If i close the RDP session all web browsers will automatically close.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible. The remote desktop does not know a user will disconnect until it happens. All prompts a user may receive during a session is client side including the "this will end the session" popup you receive when closing the remote desktop. I am sure you could make your own script by somehow tapping into the event logs of the remote desktop but it seems like a lot of effort when you can just exit out of the browser yourself.